# Get all objects from a list of objects where one of the object properties is null or empty in c#

Tags: c#, list

I'm writing a c# console app using .NET 4.7.2. I have a list of objects and I want to get a list of all the `PackageName` strings from this list where the `PackageDependency == ""`. I've seen several SO posts where it gets a single object from the list based on criteria like this using `.FirstOrDefault` but I need to get all of the objects, not just one.

Here's my object class:

```
public class PackageDetails
{
    public string PackageName { get; set; }
    public string PackageDependency { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a list and loading it up:

```
List<Objects.PackageDetails> Example = new List<Objects.PackageDetails>()
            {
                new Objects.PackageDetails {PackageName = "package1", PackageDependency = "dependency 1" }
                , new Objects.PackageDetails {PackageName = "package2" }
                , new Objects.PackageDetails {PackageName = "package3"}
                , new Objects.PackageDetails {PackageName = "package4", PackageDependency = "dependency 2" }

            };
```

Then here's where I need some guidance. Here's what I have been able to come up with so far:

```
var a = Example.Select(x => x.PackageDependency == "");
```

but when I hover over `a` it gives me the results of

> False, True, True, False

so it is identifying the objects where the `PackageDependency == ""`, but I need to have the code populate a `List<string>` that contains the `PackageName` for any object where the `PackageDependency == ""` so the output from the example above should be a `List<string>` with the values

> package2

and

> package3

If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Read the documentation for [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2). This is not the function you want. You want the [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) (no pun intended) function instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Where<T>` instead of `Select<T>`

So it should look like:

```
var a = Example.Where( x => x.PackageDependency == "" )
```

Also, I would (if you can) use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to check for the value of `Package.Dependency`

**Edit:** It looks like someone posted this same answer as a comment before I did. Didn't mean to steal thunder.

Comment: I could have sworn that I tried that previously but it did not work. But, it works exactly as expected. Thanks for the tip about `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, I used it and this is how it looks now: `var a = Example.Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.PackageDependency)); `. Accepted as answer and tried to up vote but my reputation is too low for it to show. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gharbad_The_Weak And if you really just want a list of the `PackageName` strings as you said in the question, you can tack this to the end: `.Select(x => x.PackageName).ToList()`